# Displaying code as content?

Tags: php

I have a problem as described below

1. Users fill in information in a html textarea.
2. Sometimes they enter code in the textarea.

   eg. `<script src="fancybox/jquery-1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>`
3. Now I want to display the output in a browser using PHP and the browser does not treat this as text but as code.

Is there a way to display this as text using php?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) function.

Comment: Thx for this answer, I somehow got confused between htmlspecialchars and htmlentities